# FFMpeg not installing due to vscode problem

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I am trying to code a discord music bot for a private server and when I try to install FFmpeg (npm install discord.js ffmpeg fluent-ffmpeg @discordjs/opus ytdl-core --save) it gives me a big error and I think the part that matters is this:

```
You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
```

Comment: Can you share the whole error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Visual Studio` is NOT the same thing as `vscode`.

npm is complaining about missing the compiler, not the editor. It even gives you a link to the solution: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows

Comment: Ok, thanks, sorry for being an idiot its my first time doing this stuff.